# Is there a way to fix amcharts behaviour for minperiod 'fff' with one point?

Tags: amcharts

As you see in example: http://jsfiddle.net/p2pp5vdh/, when you put your mouse on chart label at the bottom is hidden, is there any whey to fix it? I found this is only hapenning with minPeriod equal 'fff':

```
"categoryAxis": {
    "minPeriod": "fff",
    "parseDates": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [`autoMarginOffset`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#autoMarginOffset) to give some extra padding for automatically-calculated margins.

A value of 20 seems to work out pretty nice for your chart:

http://jsfiddle.net/p2pp5vdh/1/